# Can't save and close a newly created workbook in a customized folder

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, filesystemobject

I've create a macro which is able to parse some movie names from a torrent site.

What I want to do now is (***My script can satisfy the first three requirements already except the fourth one***):

```
1. Create a folder in my desktop
2. Create a new workbook after the name of the `Genre`
3. write the data in that new workbook
4. Save and close the data-ridden workbook in the newly created folder
```

This is my try so far:

```
Sub CreateAndSaveWorbook()
    Const link = "https://yts.am/browse-movies/0/all/action/0/latest"
    Dim Http As New XMLHTTP60, Html As New HTMLDocument, genre$
    Dim post As HTMLDivElement, wb As Workbook
    Dim daddr$, fdObj As Object

    daddr = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\Test\"
    Set fdObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If Not fdObj.FolderExists(daddr) Then fdObj.CreateFolder (daddr)

    With Http
        .Open "GET", link, False
        .send
        Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    genre = Html.querySelector("select[name='genre'] option[value='action']").innerText
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    wb.SaveAs daddr & genre & ".xlsx"

    For Each post In Html.getElementsByClassName("browse-movie-bottom")
        R = R + 1: wb.Sheets(1).Cells(R, 1) = post.getElementsByClassName("browse-movie-title")(0).innerText
    Next post
End Sub
```

> How can I save and close a newly created workbook in a customized folder?

Comment: what is the value of `genre`? And do you get an error when you try to save the workbook?

Comment: Value is `Action`. Nope, I don't get any error. I can see that the workbook is named after the value and is in the newly created folder and the data are duly placed in it's worksheet but the workbook is still open.

Comment: Then you only have to add `wb.Close` I guess, or change `wb.saveAs` to `wb.Close true, daddr & genre & ".xlsx"`

Comment: Did it just now but it shows a notification `want to save your changes to "Action.xlsx"?`

Comment: Also when you use the second suggestion?

Comment: Yes, it `wb.Close true, daddr & genre & ".xlsx"` did the trick. I can accept your suggestion as answer if you post one. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your answer :) :Change `wb.saveAs` to `wb.Close true, daddr & genre & ".xlsx"`